# Using todonotes in math-mode

Tags: math-mode, todonotes

Is it possible to create notes via the package `todonotes` in a displayed math environment? Here is a minimal example where it fails:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}
\[
\todo{think about it twice}foo = bar
\]
\end{document}
```

Anyone an idea?

Comment: todo notes are floats. I'd say it's probably not possible...

Answer (score 6):

The todo note needs to be added to material in the vertical list that (La)TeX is building.  You can use `\vadjust` to add such material when in other contexts.  So the following produces the desired result:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

\[
\vadjust{\todo{think about it twice}} x^2 = y^2 + z^2
\]

\end{document}
```

Note that this will not work with `eqnarray` nor the `ams` math environments, whose internals are rather different.